# Get IShellFolder with jna

Tags: java, jna

I'm new in java jna API and I have a problem with Win32 API method. I need get IShellFolder object from Win32 API because I need the IContextMenu object of the file. But when I called Win32 API method from jna ParseDisplayName, I have get the same result error:
"The system cannot find the file specified". I have attached my code below.

```
        String directory = "c:\\Users";

        IntByReference pchEaten = new IntByReference();
        pchEaten.setValue(0);
        PointerByReference ppidl = new PointerByReference();
        IntByReference pdwAttributes = new IntByReference();
        pdwAttributes.setValue(0);
        PointerByReference desktopFolder = new PointerByReference();
        WinNT.HRESULT hResult = Shell32.INSTANCE.SHGetDesktopFolder(desktopFolder);
        IShellFolder shellFolder = IShellFolder.Converter.PointerToIShellFolder(desktopFolder);
        if (COMUtils.SUCCEEDED(hResult) && shellFolder != null) {
            hResult = shellFolder.ParseDisplayName(new WinDef.HWND(Pointer.NULL), Pointer.NULL, directory, pchEaten, ppidl, pdwAttributes);
            if (COMUtils.SUCCEEDED(hResult)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
```

I have the same error with every directories which I have tested. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: You may have discovered a possible bug in JNA.  The documentation for `iShellFolder::ParseDisplayName` says the third argument, `pszDisplayName`, is "A null-terminated Unicode string with the display name." This would properly be mapped in JNA to a `WString`.  I was able to eliminate the error and return `true` by copying JNA's `IShellFolder` class to my own class, changing the type to `WString` in both function mappings, and passing `new WString(directory)` to the method. This may be worth posting on the JNA mailing list to see if they can confirm the bug or identify a better workaround.

Comment: Thank you. I have the same idea too, but I don't know how to add new method mapping to ISHellFolder. I need add IContextMenu interface too and I don't know how. I don't found any documentation in java jna API

Comment: I just copied the entire class from JNA into my own source folder, changed the `String` to `WString` in two places, and then referenced my copy in my code.

Comment: Hi daniel can you write me your code, how do you write your custom IShellFolder class? Thank you very much.

Comment: I literally copied the entire class from the JNA source code into my own project and then edited it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow!

As I mentioned in the comment, the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nf-shobjidl_core-ishellfolder-parsedisplayname) for `iShellFolder::ParseDisplayName` says the third argument, `pszDisplayName`, is "A null-terminated Unicode string with the display name."  When encountering "Unicode" in Windows docs, the "UTF-16" charset is impled.

The proper mapping for a Windows Unicode string in JNA is `WString`.  Unfortunately, JNA has mapped this argument as a `String` which is a single-byte UTF-8 encoding (even though Java stores Strings internally in UTF-16).

You can work around the issue by creating a longer `String` that converts the UTF-8 to UTF-16 (little endian) encoding (in bytes).  I previously posted a solution for ASCII that took advantage of its known encoding, but a better solution is to use the String's methods to extract the bytes as UTF-16LE, and then create a `String` object out of those bytes.  This code makes the conversion:

```
String test = "müller_test.pdf";
byte[] utf16 = test.getBytes("UTF-16LE");
System.out.println("utf16 that we need to pass:\n" + Arrays.toString(utf16));
String wString = new String(utf16);
System.out.println("Pass this to Windows:\n" + wString);
```

That produces this output:

```
utf16 (little endian) that we need to pass:
[99, 0, 58, 0, 92, 0, 85, 0, 115, 0, 101, 0, 114, 0, 115, 0]
Pass this to Windows:
m � l l e r _ t e s t . p d f
```

Unfortunately by inspecting the bytes I'm not sure if it includes the null terminator, so you may want to add the `'\u0000'` character to the end of your string before doing this manipulation.

So ultimately you would have this one-liner:

```
String wstring = new String((test + '\u0000').getBytes("UTF-16LE"));
```

Pass `wstring` to Windows where it expects the Unicode string and you're all set.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have one question on you. How can I convert this string when the file name is not in ascii encoding like file müller_test.pdf

Comment: Hi @xasd89 I updated my answer with a far more robust conversion that should work!

Comment: David I have the same problém with your robust version of the code. Systém does not find the file.

Comment: @xasd89 -- looks like Windows doesn't need the Byte Order Marker, and should be specified in Little Endian format.   Updating the solution to use `UTF-16LE` Charset should work.

Comment: Fix submitted to JNA project.  https://github.com/java-native-access/jna/pull/1127